# MTU value causing applications to hang

Tags: linux-networking, mtu

I am using CentOS 5 in my environment and it acts as a gateway for my LAN.
My eth0 interface MTU is set to 1500 (default).

```
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Recently I am facing a strange problem where some of the websites simply hangs.
If I change the MTU to 1492 the same websites open in the browser but then SSH connections
hangs at that time.

What could be the problem and how do I fix it ?

Comment: Are you changing mtu on the router, switch (if any) *and* server, or do you only change the server's mtu?

Comment: @MikePennington I am changing the MTU in the server (CentOS 5) which acts as a router for a LAN. From the server I am trying to browse the websites or make a SSH connection to servers outside our network.

Comment: Check your firewall and make sure you aren't blocking ICMP type 3.

Answer (score 0):

All interfaces in the subnet need to have the same mtu... set them all to 1492, including your ethernet switches (if possible)